# Stopping orientation change with side-keyboard (Android)

Tags: android, static, keyboard, orientation, portrait

I am wondering how I can make the orientation of the screen permanent, even when the phone has a slide-out keyboard. This is the code I have:

```
<activity android:name=".AppName" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```